# Running Visual Studio 2019 CPU instrumentation profiling programmatically

Tags: c#, visual-studio, profiling, visual-studio-2019, instrumentation

Assume I have some C# program. I can run instrumentation profiling in Visual Studio 2019 via the menu `Debug > Performance Profiler...`, checking `Instrumentation` and then clicking `Start`.

This work well for small project but for larger projects it would be nice to be able to start the instrumentation programmatically to target just whatever you are interested in.

Is there some way to programmatically start the instrumentation, then stop it and finally saving a report?

It's fine if I have to build the projects with some special options enabled or run some instrumentation initialization code, but I want to be able to limit the scope of the actual report. Something like:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
        // Start instrumentation here
        Foo(10);
        // Stop instrumentation here
        // Save instrumentation report here
    }

    private static void Foo(int more)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(more);
        if (more > 0)
        {
            Foo(more - 1);
            Foo(more - 1);
        }
    }
}
```